# System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (AddScopped)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created the following service:

```
public class PelicuaService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicacionDbContext> _TFGContext;
    public PelicuaService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicacionDbContext> TFGContext)
    {
        _TFGContext = TFGContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<Pelicula>> GetAllPeliculas()
    {
        using var dbContext = await _TFGContext.CreateDbContextAsync();

        return await (from p in dbContext.Peliculas
                      select new Pelicula
                      {
                          IdPelicula = p.IdPelicula,
                          Titulo = p.Titulo,
                          Descripcion = p.Descripcion,
                          Director = p.Director,
                          AnioLanzamiento = p.AnioLanzamiento,
                          IdGenero = p.IdGenero

                      }).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

and in the main file I have put the following:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<PelicuaService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

and the model file is the following:

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tfg.Data.Models
{
    public partial class Pelicula
    {
        public int IdPelicula { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public int? AnioLanzamiento { get; set; }
        public int? IdGenero { get; set; }

        public virtual Genero IdGeneroNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what can I do?

this is th error:
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: tfg.Data.Services.PelicuaService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: tfg.Data.Services.PelicuaService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[tfg.Data.Models.ApplicacionDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'tfg.Data.Services.PelicuaService'.)'

I put this

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

but the application does not start

Comment: Did you forget to register the DbContextFacory? There's no `AddDbContextFactory` or even `AddDbContext` in the registration snippet. BTW it's a bad idea to violate the EF Core naming conventions. You now have to manually specify all the metadata that would be generated automatically, eg specify that `IdPelicula` is the primary key of the  `Pelicula` class. That increases the chance of mistakes

Comment: where I can see  the DbContextFacory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to register your IDbContextFactory in the DI container as you do with the PelicuaService. For instance:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IDbContextFactory<>), typeof(Factory<>));
```

Here Factory is the class implementing the IDbContextFactory interface. I hope this may help.